# Copying corporate mail from necessary OU in Label

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to сopying corporate mail from necessary OU (Gsuit) in group (Label) contacts.
Is it possible to make a script, that allows you to upload users from certain OU to a group (label) of contacts? Before that I tried to do this by copying from the directory to the label, but as it proved impossible. I am trying to implement it through the Google Apps Scripts.